# Can $(\mathbb Q,+)$ be made a vector space over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Does there exist an external multiplication $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ w.r.t. which $\mathbb Q$ forms a vector space over $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 10):

No. All non-trivial vector spaces, $V$, over $\Bbb R$ have at least one non-zero vector, $v$, hence $\Bbb R\cong \Bbb R\cdot v=\{r\cdot v \;|\; r\in\Bbb R\}\subseteq V$, hence must be uncountably infinite.